# PHP Вставка значений в БД по названию массива

Tags: php, mysql, sql, массивы, insert

Есть массив:

```
array(4) { ["question_result_1"]=> string(1) "1" ["question_result_2"]=> string(1) "2" ["teacher_id"]=> string(1) "1"}
```

Нужно чтобы из названий элементов этого массива сформировался такой запрос:

INSERT INTO tbl_name (question_result_1,question_result_2,teacher_id) VALUES(1,2,1);

Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: `implode(',', array_keys($array))` и `implode(',', array_fill(0, count($array), '?'))`. С помощью подготовленных запросов вставить данные `array_values($array)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это хороший вопрос, но правильный ответ на него не так прост.

Начнем с того, что динамически формировать запрос на вставку нет смысла. Потому что набор полей будет всегда один и тот же, и эту часть запроса можно написать один раз. А значения тем более **никогда не должны подставляться в запрос напрмую**, а только через плейсхолдеры.

Поэтому для решения этой конкретной задачи мы просто составим запрос заранее, подставив на место значений особые переменные, которые называются плейсхолдеры

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_name (question_result_1,question_result_2,teacher_id)
        VALUES(:question_result_1,:question_result_2,:teacher_id)";
```

После этого данный запрос можно будет выполнить любое количество раз, используя массив, который описан в вопросе. Для этого мы будем использовать PDO

```
$data = ["question_result_1"=>1, "question_result_2"=>2, "teacher_id"=>1];
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_name (question_result_1,question_result_2,teacher_id)
        VALUES(:question_result_1,:question_result_2,:teacher_id)";
$pdo->prepare($sql)->execute($data);
```

Таким образом, передавая массив $data с разными значениями, мы всегда будем выполнять новый запрос - что нам и требовалось!

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте так. Вполне себе безопасно, если Вы не используете данные из GET/POST источника.

```php
    $set = ""
    foreach($array as $key=>$value){
      $set .= $set ."`". $key ."` = '". $value ."', ";
    }
    $query = str_replace(", ;", ";", "INSERT INTO `tablename` SET ". $set .";");
```

Comment: Так делать ни в коем случае нельзя. Это готовая SQL инъекция

Comment: Ну да, автор не указал что данные GET или POST. В принципе двери хостера всегда могут быть открыты для инъекцирующего кодера